# FreeBSD pkg does not find any packages; where to start debugging

Tags: freebsd

I installed the latest FreeBSD 11 snapshot on a RPI2.
Installing/making a package from ports works fine.

```
pkg upgrade
```

works fine as well, but

```
pkg search nano
```

does not find any packages.
I come from Debian. Where do I start finding the problem?

I already deleted /var/db/pkg/repo-FreeBSD.sqlite and ran

```
pkg upgrade
```

again.
But this didn't change anything.

Added as requested:

```
pkg -vv
Version                 : 1.5.2
PKG_DBDIR = "/var/db/pkg";
PKG_CACHEDIR = "/var/cache/pkg";
PORTSDIR = "/usr/ports";
INDEXDIR = "";
INDEXFILE = "INDEX-11";
HANDLE_RC_SCRIPTS = false;
DEFAULT_ALWAYS_YES = false;
ASSUME_ALWAYS_YES = false;
REPOS_DIR [
    "/etc/pkg/",
    "/usr/local/etc/pkg/repos/",
]
PLIST_KEYWORDS_DIR = "";
SYSLOG = true;
ABI = "FreeBSD:11:armv6";
ALTABI = "freebsd:11:armv6:32:el:eabi:softfp";
DEVELOPER_MODE = false;
VULNXML_SITE = "http://vuxml.freebsd.org/freebsd/vuln.xml.bz2";
FETCH_RETRY = 3;
PKG_PLUGINS_DIR = "/usr/local/lib/pkg/";
PKG_ENABLE_PLUGINS = true;
PLUGINS [
]
DEBUG_SCRIPTS = false;
PLUGINS_CONF_DIR = "/usr/local/etc/pkg/";
PERMISSIVE = false;
REPO_AUTOUPDATE = true;
NAMESERVER = "";
EVENT_PIPE = "";
FETCH_TIMEOUT = 30;
UNSET_TIMESTAMP = false;
SSH_RESTRICT_DIR = "";
PKG_ENV {
}
PKG_SSH_ARGS = "";
DEBUG_LEVEL = 0;
ALIAS {
    all-depends = "query %dn-%dv";
    annotations = "info -A";
    build-depends = "info -qd";
    cinfo = "info -Cx";
    comment = "query -i \"%c\"";
    csearch = "search -Cx";
    desc = "query -i \"%e\"";
    download = "fetch";
    iinfo = "info -ix";
    isearch = "search -ix";
    prime-list = "query -e '%a = 0' '%n'";
    leaf = "query -e '%#r == 0' '%n-%v'";
    list = "info -ql";
    noauto = "query -e '%a == 0' '%n-%v'";
    options = "query -i \"%n - %Ok: %Ov\"";
    origin = "info -qo";
    provided-depends = "info -qb";
    raw = "info -R";
    required-depends = "info -qr";
    roptions = "rquery -i \"%n - %Ok: %Ov\"";
    shared-depends = "info -qB";
    show = "info -f -k";
    size = "info -sq";
}
CUDF_SOLVER = "";
SAT_SOLVER = "";
RUN_SCRIPTS = true;
CASE_SENSITIVE_MATCH = false;
LOCK_WAIT = 1;
LOCK_RETRIES = 5;
SQLITE_PROFILE = false;
WORKERS_COUNT = 0;
READ_LOCK = false;
PLIST_ACCEPT_DIRECTORIES = false;
IP_VERSION = 0;
AUTOMERGE = true;
VERSION_SOURCE = "";
CONSERVATIVE_UPGRADE = true;
PKG_CREATE_VERBOSE = false;


Repositories:
  FreeBSD: { 
    url             : "pkg+http://pkg.FreeBSD.org/FreeBSD:11:armv6/latest",
    enabled         : yes,
    priority        : 0,
    mirror_type     : "SRV",
    signature_type  : "FINGERPRINTS",
    fingerprints    : "/usr/share/keys/pkg"
  }
```

Comment: What does mean: "works fine as well"? Please post output of `pkg -vv`!

Comment: Meant "works fine" as in "no error message".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't yet official package repository to RPI so you can't install any official program yet.

There is an unofficial repository for ARM (and FreeBSD 11) [here](http://chips.ysv.freebsd.org/packages/) but it seems it's empty.

I'm maintaning a small repository too but for FreeBSD 10.x - see [here](http://pkg.uzsolt.hu/).

**Update:** now (07.02.2015.) the unofficial FreeBSD 11 repository contains packages.

**Update2**: [official FreeBSD11 armv6 package repository](http://pkg.freebsd.org/FreeBSD:11:armv6/)